# Use samples to estimate standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

The followings are independent samples from two normal populations. Both of which have the same standard deviation.

16, 17, 19, 20, 18 and 3, 4, 8

How to estimate standard deviation?

Answer (score 1):

Given independent samples of size $n_1$, sample variance $s_1^2$, and $n_2$ with sample variance $s_2^2$, the pooled estimate of the common variance is
$$
s^2=\frac{(n_1-1)s_1^2+(n_2-1)s_2^2}{n_1+n_2-2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You could compute $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\overline{x})^2$ for both samples and then take the average.